# Prove that turing machines and the lambda calculus are equivalent

Tags: turing-machines, lambda-calculus, simulation

It is known that a turing machine and the lambda calculus are equivalent in power. I now want to try to prove this myself. I think proving that the lambda calculus is at least as powerful as a turing machine should be relatively easy, by trying to simulate a turing machine in lambda calculus. This should be possible by storing the tape as a list with some encoding, and encoding a transition function as a lambda term.

However, I'm having trouble with proving that a turing machine is at least as powerful as lambda calculus. Any pointers on how to start trying?

Comment: You just need to show how a Turing machine can evaluate $\lambda$-terms. If you already know that, could you try to ask a more specific question so we can work out what part you need help with?

Comment: I know how to simulate a turing machine using lambda calculus. I'm not sure, however, how to evaluate lambda -terms with a turing machine.

Comment: Build a Turing machine that acts as an interpreter for the lambda calculus. You should be able to find lots of resources in books and on the web for how to build an interpreter for the lambda calculus. For instance, see *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* by Abelson and Sussman.

Comment: Do you know how to build an interpreter for the lambda-calculus?

Comment: @D.W. So the strategy would be to put a lambda expression on a tape... and then define sets of Turing machine transition functions to mimic each lambda transformation rule?

Comment: Start by figuring out whether you know how to build a lambda calculus interpreter, without regard to Turing machines.  In other words, see if you can work out an algorithm or pseudocode to do it.  If yes, then the only question remaining is how to translate that into a Turing machine.  But first figure out which part you are having trouble with: are you having trouble with the first part (how to build an interpreter for the lambda-calculus) or the second part (how to turn the pseudocode for such an interpreter into a Turing machine).

Comment: @user19775 i am badly confused with this lambda calculus. I understand designing Turing machine to compute "adding two numbers". In fact there are many good you tube short videos explaining this - however Lambda calculus model I am finding hard to understand. You mentioned _by trying to simulate a turing machine in lambda calculus_ , so it is possible to convert that model to Lambda calculus ? Any good pointers, please ?