# Iterative algorithm for assembly index?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, recursion, partial-order

[DOI: 10.3390/e24070884](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/24/7/884) provides pseudocode for computing the assembly index of an object. It is written as recursive algorithm, which might be fine. But I would like to implement an iterative version of this in Python which has a recursion depth limit. Although this limit can be changed within a given program, an iterative algorithm circumvents unconventionally changing the recursion limit.

[image]

What is an equivalent iterative algorithm for computing the assembly index?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [Iteration can replace Recursion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67897/iteration-can-replace-recursion). My question is not concerned with the existence of an iterative algorithm, but rather requests an instantiation of such an algorithm in a particular case. "Please show me an emerald" is not a duplicate of "do precious gems exist?".

Comment: Some answers there do outline the approach. Just maintain the recursion stack manually.

Comment: BTW, as I recall, a Python solution that works everywhere is to set the stack size and the recursion limit (inside the python), and then create a new thread, which adopts these parameters. The functions should be `threading.stack_size` and `setrecursionlimit`.